# I can't generate pitchipoy armature

Tags: rigify

This is my 1st time using pitchipoy armature and i can't generate it. This is the error messages :
[image: error messages]

[image: side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic rig generating scripts are only designed to work with the provided meta rigs. While there is some ability to alter the rigs, they tend to be very specific about bone names and parenting relationships.

You will need to replace the bone/s that you deleted and probably get the parenting configured to match the original rig. This could mean it is easier to add a new meta rig and start again.

Even if you don't want to use all of the bones provided, you can leave them there and not weight paint them to any part of your mesh. Then you can place the bones on a separate [bone layer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/properties/skeleton.html#armature-layers) that you can leave hidden so that they aren't in your way when you are animating.

Comment: I didn't delete any bone, I just moved it to match the mesh.

Comment: Did you maybe rename one? or clear the parent setting?

Comment: I think no, i'll redo later.

Comment: My bad, I made some mistakes. I redo it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try "Rigify", it has great controls and can be "Set parent to -> With automatic weights"

[image]

Best of luck, It will make your life easy :)

Please take a look, all controls 
[image]

Can you please try to use this rig :
[image]

After adjusting bones as per your character, please don't forget to apply, scale, rotation and location to the rig before generating the controls.

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Did you make the controls manually ?

Comment: No, Rigify is doing the job for us, and its on a single click

Comment: Please take a kind look of updated image

Comment: @BlenderForYou the pitchipoy rig is one of rigify's meta rigs, it is the rigify generate rig button that gets the error.

Comment: Opps sorry about that, I did not notice the child name of rigify, can you please hide the mesh and show only the meta rig, seems that lip bone is a problem

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: Please have a look on the updated answer, if it worked for you please accept the answer.